# Data download issue in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've run into a problem with `downloadHandler()` in Shiny:
I want to choose from three data sets to download any file via this function. The dropdown menu in the app shows the three files to choose from, but when I click download it's always the first dataset that is downloaded.

The overall code is pretty long, but this is the relevant part. I appreciate if someone points out to where I'm making a mistake:

```
ui <- fluidPage(  tabPanel("Downloading Data",
                  titlePanel("Download Data"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      selectInput("dataset",label="Choose a dataset:",c("m.census","f.census","mortality.rates")),
                      downloadButton("downloadData","Download")
                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      tableOutput("tab3")
                    )
                  )
                )
              )

server <- function(input, output) {
  datasetInput<-reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
       "m.census"=m.census,
       "f.census"=f.census,
       "mortality.rates"=mortality.rates)
  })

  output$tab3<-renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

  output$downloadData<-downloadHandler(
    filename=function(){
      paste(input$dataset,".csv",sep="")
    },

    content=function(file){
      write.csv(datasetInput(),file,row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code with `code` sections in the future.

Comment: @Nooza I just tried your exact code with inbuilt R dataset  and The code works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks @amrrs ,I have three other tabs running other functions, do you think the issue may be relevant to that?

Comment: @Nooza Do you have the same `id` repeated?

Comment: @amrrs no I don't